# Evince preferences (double page view, first page on right side), how do I force it manually

Tags: evince

I am viewing various PDF files with Evince. It has an option to display the first page of a document on the right side when viewing it in double page mode, so that one sees the pages like in an opened book (even pages left, odd right).

For reasons unknown to me, the corresponding setting for first page on right side (it's actually "two pages - odd pages left" with a checkbox that is checked) is often grayed out in the GUI. Is it possible to force the setting in a configuration file or with a command-line option?

Comment: to see the problem.. i have just installed evince.. snap version.. and it is working like this.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI1nG.gif out of the box.. is it different in your case?

Comment: It's a different language, but basically the same to yours. Now I found out that it seems to be working when I reopen the document, but not when I open it for the first time, so it's probably a bug. And if so then Evince does remember which file was opened - just another thing I'd like to get rid of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug in Evince, specifically: [Odd Pages Left option disabled/enabled at wrong time (#602) · Issues · GNOME / evince · GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/602)

It should be fixed in recent versions of Evince, which version of Evince and Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Yes it seems it is fixed now.